# Problems using pygerrit.rest

Tags: git, rest, gerrit

I have pygerrit installed in my machine. I ran below command to install it :

```
pip install pygerrit
```

But I am getting error when try to import rest  :

```
from pygerrit.rest import GerritRestAPI
>>ImportError: No module named rest
```

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem with pygerrit 0.2.2 installed in a virtualenv.
When running

> > > imp.find_module("pygerrit")
> > >       (None, '/path/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygerrit', ('', '', 5))

ls /local/repo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygerrit
**init**.py   client.py   error.py   events.py   models.py   ssh.py   stream.py
**init**.pyc  client.pyc  error.pyc  events.pyc  models.pyc  ssh.pyc  stream.pyc

When comparing that to the contents in github the folder "rest" is missing:
https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/pygerrit/tree/master/pygerrit

So there seems to be a problem with the installer. 
Try copying the files from Github instead and it should work better.

/Daniel

Comment: This was fixed in version 0.2.3 which had not been uploaded to pypi previously, but now is.